# Flash AIR: prevent exiting fullscreen with command+w

Tags: actionscript-3, air, fullscreen, exit

OK, so I've been at this for a good couple of hours now and I'm starting to rage.

I am making a kiosk-app in flash (air) which should not allow users to exit fullscreen mode by any other means than typing in a password. This has proved somewhat impossible, as it appears you just can't prevent users from using ctrl+alt+delete or command+alt+esc or for that matter alt+tab. But at the very least I want to prevent them from using escape, alt+f4, command+q and command+w.

After a fair bit of googling I've got escape, alt+f4 and command+q down. Basically I'm just setting listeners for the CLOSE, CLOSING and EXITING event on stage.nativeWindow and preventingDefault(). The CLOSE and EXITING events never fire in this case, they're just there for good measure. I'm handling ESC simply by listening for KEY_UP and preventing it. However:

Command+w is refusing to cooperate. It appears to be doing something which minimizes the fullscreen before dispatching the CLOSING event. So, the question is:

What is it, and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a listener for command+w, and, brutally:

if (this.stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
                {
                    this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
//you'd need to play with this and see if it suits your needs or not, if not, don't use it.
this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT; 
                }

It's kind of a pain in the keister if the app loses focus, it can't listen for keystrokes.  My solution for this has been to set up a loop that frequently steals focus - but this is not good for an app that could ride in the background.  For a kiosk-type app, and a system that's intended to only run one app, this is an acceptable compromise.

So at the same time, you can also set, in this loop, a command like the one above, that restores the app to full-screen.  You'll have to mess around with the timer frequency that dictates how often this loop runs and steals focus - more than 5 or so times per second (depending on what else is in your app) can really be a cpu and memory suck.

The main problem is: I don't think there's a way for AIR to totally kill these escape keystrokes in kiosk mode.  It's kind of a security "risk".  (by the way, I think that the ESC key also invokes windowed-mode from full-screen; Don't quote me on that-).

I guess, another workaround would be to periodically kick the app into the BACKGROUND.  This would prevent the control+w kestrokes from ever being caught by the app.  But I think that the behavior of the program would be pretty annoying if there was any other interactivity required.

Comment: Oops, pressed enter...

You can't listen for cmd+w, when both those keys are pressed they are not considered a keyboardevent. As for going back to fullscreen from normal, I did attempt this, but I found I had to set an arbitrary delay for it to work, otherwise I would get an endless stream of CLOSING events. Hardly ideal.

As the fullscreen mode has a form to fill out, I can't kick it into the background. As you say, there's no way to completely shut down escape keystrokes short of locking up the keyboard so I've ended up just throwing my hands in the air singing "I just don't care!".

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (although, in this example, I am calling a function that explicitly captures ctrl+w to go to windowed-mode, the opposite of what you're asking for; I used this code this way, because I have some logging operations built in to what I'm doing, so I needed to intercept and control the keystroke activity):

```
if (event.ctrlKey)
{
     //ctrl+F & ctrl+K -> go full screen;
     if(event.charCode == 102 || event.charCode == 107)
     {
          makeFullScreen();
     }
     //ctrl+S & ctrl+Q -> write to logfile, exit program;
     if(event.charCode == 115 || event.charCode == 113)
     {
          instrumentedExit();
     }
     //ctrl+W -> exit kiosk;
     if(event.charCode == 119)
     {
          windowedMode();
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the opposite thing is a bit of an issue as what I was looking for was whatever caused cmd+w to exit fullscreen when I was able to catch and prevent the CLOSING event :P

Answer (score 0):

An AIR application simply cannot interfere with system/task keys, however a native application can which means a native extension.

e.g in windows you could call SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, ...)

Comment: Well no, I can't really interfere with the keystrokes themselves, but I can control how the program responds to them. I mean am already catching the CLOSING event dispatched by cmd+w, my problem is that something happens just before it that exits fullscreen.